# How to get Liquibase to add more data to DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table?

Tags: liquibase

In our build server, we have a number of feature branches get deployed against one database. The problem is sometimes some buggy scripts in one branch causes LB to exit without releasing the lock. The problem is there is no easy way to find out what branch caused this. We may have up to 30 branches getting deployed constantly as there are new changes against the branch.

Is there any way (or can we have new feature in Liquibase) to set the instance name and the name can be stored in LOCKEDBY column of table DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK so we can easily find out what branch/instance caused the issue?

Currently, LOCKEDBY has only IP in it which is the same for all the instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to achive this you need to patch Liquibase somewhere here:

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/ed4bd55c36f52980a43f1ac2c7ce8f819e606e38/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/lockservice/DatabaseChangeLogLock.java

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/ed4bd55c36f52980a43f1ac2c7ce8f819e606e38/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/lockservice/StandardLockService.java

to fetch additional variable somehow (property file/env variable/etc) and store in the table.

Btw, be careful with deploying multiple branches with the same database instance, because it is possible that you will make a change in DB structure for one branch, that will break another one.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a system property which gets insert into the **LOCKEDBY** column:

```
System.setProperty("liquibase.hostDescription", "some value");
```

Comment: Thanks. We realised that it uses hostname and because our application gets deployed in a docker container and we didn't specified a name for it, it was using ip address. Now we set the name and the correct name gets inserted rather than ip